# Aspose .Net word Add items with in the list

Tags: list, aspose.words

I am new on Aspose and struggling to add items (like Table, Free Text without the numbering) with in the lists. I wanted to achieve something like below.
I am able to successfully add list and Indented items but when I tried to add table or free text there, it is providing list numbers to all other cell/text items.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See Aspose.Words documentation to learn how to [work with list](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/working-with-lists/). If you are using DocumentBuilder to build your document, you can use code like the following to build the required document:

```cs
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

// Start default numbering here.
builder.ListFormat.ApplyNumberDefault();
builder.Writeln("Bullet Point 1");
builder.Writeln("Bullet Point 2");
// Remember the list.
List lst = builder.ListFormat.List;
// Stop numbering.
builder.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers();

// Table title
builder.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
builder.Font.Bold= true;
builder.Writeln("Report");
builder.Font.ClearFormatting();
builder.ParagraphFormat.ClearFormatting();

// Build table (For demonstration purpose fill it dummy data)
builder.StartTable();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        builder.InsertCell();
        builder.Write($"cell_{i}_{j}");
    }
    builder.EndRow();
}
builder.EndTable();

// Continue numbering.
builder.ListFormat.List = lst;
builder.Writeln("Bullet Point 3");
builder.Writeln("Bullet Point 4");
// indent list
builder.ListFormat.ListIndent();
int listLevel = builder.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber;
builder.Writeln("Internal Bullet Point 1");
// Stop numbering.
builder.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers();
// Insert simple paragraph
builder.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 100;
builder.Writeln("Free Text Paragraph 1");
builder.ParagraphFormat.ClearFormatting();
// Continue numbering.
builder.ListFormat.List = lst;
builder.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = listLevel;
builder.Writeln("Internal Bullet Point 2");
// Stop numbering.
builder.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers();
// Insert simple paragraph
builder.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 100;
builder.Writeln("Free Text Paragraph 1");
builder.ParagraphFormat.ClearFormatting();
// Continue numbering.
builder.ListFormat.List = lst;
builder.Writeln("Bullet Point 5");
// indent list / another list can be used here if required.
builder.ListFormat.ListIndent();
listLevel = builder.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber;
builder.Writeln("Internal Bullet Point 1");
// Stop numbering.
builder.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers();
// Insert simple paragraph
builder.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 100;
builder.Writeln("Free Text Paragraph 1");
builder.ParagraphFormat.ClearFormatting();
// Continue numbering.
builder.ListFormat.List = lst;
builder.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = listLevel;
builder.Writeln("Internal Bullet Point 2");
// Stop numbering.
builder.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers();
// Insert simple paragraph
builder.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 100;
builder.Writeln("Free Text Paragraph 1");
builder.ParagraphFormat.ClearFormatting();

doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
```

Comment: I could not get how to change number to Bullet point at listLevel

Comment: You can use `ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault`. Also, you can specify `ListLevel.NumberFormat`  and set it to a bullet symbol and `ListLevel.NumberStyle` to `NumberStyle.Bullet`.  For example:             builder.ListFormat.ListLevel.NumberFormat = "\x2022";
            builder.ListFormat.ListLevel.NumberStyle = NumberStyle.Bullet;